# Is possible to use the instance ValueEventListener for two different calls with addValueEventListener, at same Activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the method addValueEventListener as shown below:

```
public List<MyClassModel> DoRequestCards() {

        valueEventListener = getDatabaseReference()
                .child("Example")
                .child(Objects.requireNonNull(getFirebaseAuthInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid())
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        list.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            MyClassModel model = data.getValue(MyClassModel.class);
                            //Retrieves UniqueKey from each example
                            Objects.requireNonNull(card).setUniqueId(data.getKey());
                            list.add(model);
                        }
                        taskListener.OnSuccess(); //call interface method
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        taskListener.OnError(databaseError.getMessage()); //call interface method
                    }
                });

        return list;
    }
```

It's possible to create another method to retrieve different list with different data fetching again `addValueEventListener` at same `valueEventListener` instance ? Or should I create another instance to it (because they're at same activity and need each to stay listening their changes) ?

I'm using the same instance of ValueEventListener at different activities, but when activity stops (onStop) I remove it (I've no problems with that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same listener twice.  That's not a problem.  You can check the snapshot in the listener which location triggered the listener.

Comment: So, do I need to handle this, or is it automatic ? I mean, if I use the same instance, when I call removeEventListenerat, at onStop, they will both be removed ? Same for the add itens (need handle or it's automatic - the method will know what data I'm using) ?

Comment: No, you have to remove the listener from each reference individually.